# D-Link 6850U dropping LAN connections

Tags: router

My router seems to be dropping connections briefly on the LAN side.  I say this because a) My ISP reports no interruptions and b) I'm seeing interruption both with VPN connections and with watching videos from a hard disc connected to the router's USB port -- which is obviously only internal.

Can anybody explain my experience?  Are there configuration options that I can use to prevent -- or at least minimize -- these interruptions?

I turned on the router's "system log" and set it to "warning" level.  I see a bunch of lines that look like this:

> warn  radvd[3801]: received RA from fe80::290:4cff:fe0c:0

this:

> alert kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp1.1 OUT=

and this:

> alert kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp1.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=110.55.1.230
>   DST=109.67.177.38 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=24881 DF
>   PROTO=TCP SPT=54569 DPT=30650 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
>   MARK=0x8000002

I don't know what any of them means, but perhaps that will help someone diagnose my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem? Do you have any logs from your router / windows / etc.? What kind of router is it? How is it configured. You should really put in some more effort in this question.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm not sure what information is relevant and network logs tend to be very big.  As for the kind of router, I mention that in the Subject -- unless there's some other, more specific piece of identification...?